# Find out what reads from the clipboard

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging

Since iOS14 our app displays a read Clipboard notice, however we don't read anything and it must be a result of some SDK (probably Facebook)

But how to confirm that or breakpoint on the moment the clipboard is accessed, to find out what reads from the cliboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You can place [symbolic breakpoints](https://jayeshkawli.ghost.io/xcode-symbolic-breakpoints-break-at-specific-method-call/) using XCode, which will trigger even if they are called deep from within a library.

From what I have gathered, you can only access the clipboard using [`UIPasteboard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipasteboard). You should probably add a breakpoint on the Objective-C method `generalPasteboard`.

Comment: Thanks, Firebase Deeplinks were the cause!!! https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5893